# issue with a function that returns an enumeration

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that returns an enumeration. The function accepts a string. Uses the algorithm library to lower case the string and then use if statements to check what time of enum it is.

the enumeration is defined as:

```
 enum Location {Abs, Front, Back, Trap};
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
     warning: variable 'enum_location' is used uninitialized whenever
  'if' condition is false [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
    if(location_string == "abs")
```

the following is the function:

```
  milestone::Location Task::convert_to_enum(std::string location_string)
  {
    std::transform(location_string.begin(), location_string.end(), location_string.begin(), ::tolower);

    milestone::Location enum_location;

    if(location_string == "trap")
    {
      enum_location = milestone::Trap;
    }
    else if (location_string == "back")
      {
        enum_location = milestone::Back;
      }
      else if(location_string == "front")
      {
        enum_location = milestone::Front;
      }
      else if(location_string == "abs")
        {
          enum_location = milestone::Abs;
        }

    return enum_location;
  }
```

Comment: If you answer the following, you will understand the compiler's warning: what happens when the passed-in string is none of the values being checked for here, hhhhmmmmmmmmm?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchi ok so it should be initialized to some default value, if the passed-in string is none of the values it'll either always evaulate to true or either false? if so how do I go about initializing a enum to a default value if I am not mistaken

Comment: It should be either initialized to some default value at the beginning, return a default value in a final `else` block, or raise an exception if the string doesn't match. You may also want to put your `else if` in one line as that is what is typically done and it may be a bit hard for other people to read if you don't do that.

Comment: It's up to you to figure out what the function should return, or do, if the passed-in string does not match any of the values being tested for. Either return some default value; or perhaps throw an exception.

Comment: @a-one "it'll either always evaulate to true or either false?" Since the function must return an enumeration value, either you know a default value that is good if returned for invalid strings in input (you may want to add the `Invalid` value in your enumeration for the purpose and treat the case in your calling code; or just return a benign one, valid when anything else fails) or you throw an exception.

Comment: ok thanks guys throwing an exception worked!